# Linkedin authentication failing

Tags: authentication, oauth, linkedin-api

I hope am am posting this in the proper place.

I am trying to work through the tutorial `make your first LinkedIn API call using OAuth 2.0.`

http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication

a. Generate Authorization Code by redirecting user to LinkedIn's authorization dialog

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code
&client_id=YOUR_API_KEY
&scope=SCOPE
&state=STATE
&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
```

Filling this out:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code
&client_id=123456789
&scope=r_basicprofile%r_network%
&state=abcdefghi
&redirect_uri=http://www.socialinnovationlab.net
```

which gives a uri of

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=123456789&scope=r_basicprofile%r_network%&state=abcdefghi&redirect_uri=http://www.socialinnovationlab.net
```

And this gives the linkedin auth form as it should.

b. Request Access Token by exchanging the authorization_code for it

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code
&code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE    ****I think this is the above uri?******
&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
&client_id=YOUR_API_KEY
&client_secret=YOUR_SECRET_KEY
```

I have:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code
                                       &code=https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=123456789&scope=r_basicprofile%r_network%&state=abcdefghi&redirect_uri=http://www.socialinnovationlab.net
&redirect_uri=http://www.socialinnovationlab.net
&client_id=123456789
&client_secret=1212121212
```

Which givies a uri of:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=123456789&scope=r_basicprofile%r_network%&state=abcdefghi&redirect_uri=http://www.socialinnovationlab.net&redirect_uri=http://www.socialinnovationlab.net&client_id=123456789&client_secret=1212121212
```

When I try to go to this address I get the error:

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"missing required parameters, includes an invalid parameter value, parameter more then once. : client_id"}
```

any idea where I went wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Tim did you figure this out? I have the same error as you. I can get the access token successfully using curl but not in Python at all. Always get 400s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In step a. when you navigate to

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=123456789&scope=r_basicprofile%r_network%&state=abcdefghi&redirect_uri=http://www.socialinnovationlab.net
```

you'll see LinkedIn auth form. Once you submit the form you'll be redirected to

```
http://www.socialinnovationlab.net?code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE&state=abcdefghi
```

Parameter `code` in the above URL will contain your authorization code. That is the authorization code you'll need to use in `code` parameter of the URL in step b.